# excel formula - how to match column A with B and return a text value of Column C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

May I ask how can I achieve the below if I want to have change number matched with approve number and return staff in another column?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjxx8.png)

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: where do you get the names from?

Comment: Please describe your issue using text rather than images. You may use images to further clarify your writing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point. The #N/A values is the result of VLOOKUP not finding a matching row. I'll leave it to you to solve that part.

[image]